# Setting state with values inside an object

Tags: react-hooks

Im basically trying to set the state with the  City value but when I set thee state and console log the state its always empty. Im even console logging along the way.

sample city object from first console.log:
{_id: '625a495ae4bea1099502f824',
City: 'Dakhla Oasis'
Country: 'Egypt'
}

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function Cities() {

  const [singlecity, setSingleCity] = useState('');

  function GetSingleCity() {
    console.log(city)
    setSingleCity(city.City);
    console.log(singlecity);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

`setState` function in react is asynchronous, so if you `console.log` right after the set state, you will not see the updated value immediately. However if yo try to render the state, you will see the rendered html will be updated. If you want to `console.log` the latest value of `singleCity`, you could either move the `console.log` outside `GetSingleCity`, so console.log will run on every re-render, or put console.log inside a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {console.log(singleCity)}, [singleCity])
```

useEffect will run the callback every time the state `singleCity` has changed, so you will see the updated value